# NUnit Test: random input for TestCase in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

How to set random string in unit Test for TestCase Attribute? How to create a test with random inputs in c#?

```
        [Test]
        [TestCase("")]
        public async Task TestGet(string inp){....}


        public string CreateRandomString(int size)
         {
           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           Random random = new Random();

           char c;
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           {
            c = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 
             65)));
            builder.Append(c);
            }
          return builder.ToString();
         }
```

Comment: Are you using NUnit (please add appropriate tag)? Then take a look at the [TestCaseSource](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

With NUnit, you can use a [`TestCaseSource`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html):

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(CreateRandomStrings))]
public void TestGet(string input)
{
  // your test ...
}

public IEnumerable<string> CreateRandomStrings()
{
  // create 5 random strings
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    yield return CreateRandomString(10);
  }
}


private static readonly Random random = new Random();
public string CreateRandomString(int size)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   char c;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
    c = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
    builder.Append(c);
   }
   return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TestCaseSource` attribute to do that:

```
public static string RandomString()
{
    const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    int size = 50;
    char[] chars = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        chars[i] = alphabet[rand.Next(alphabet.Length)];
    }

    var a = new string(chars);
    return a;
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(RandomString))]
public void TestGet(string random)
{
    // Do something
}
```